# How to get refresh token from Identity server4 in .net framework Mvc

Tags: openid-connect, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4

How can I get refresh token in .net framework MVC? please give a suggestion.

Comment: You need to provide some more information: Which flow are you using? Are you using OpenIdConnect via Javascript? In any case you need to configure the client to have offline_access enabled in order to get refresh token

Comment: I have followed this link

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)/Startup.cs

but still not getting refresh token